# Replace one regex match with another and vice versa

Tags: r, string, replace

I need to replace in string `foo bar foo bar bar foo` all  `foo` to `bar` and all `bar` to `foo`. So the result should look like `bar foo bar foo foo bar`.

I have tried this way:

```
library(stringr)

my_str <- "foo bar foo bar bar foo"
rslt <- str_replace_all(my_str, c("foo", "bar"), c("bar", "foo"))

print(rslt)
```

but instead I got `"bar bar bar bar bar bar" "foo foo foo foo foo foo"`.

**Question:** How to correct my code so I get `bar foo bar foo foo bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to `split` and replace

```
str_c(setNames(v1, rpl)[str_split(my_str, "\\s+")[[1]]], collapse = ' ')
#[1] "bar foo bar foo foo bar"
```

---

Or another option is `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\w+)", setNames(as.list(v1), rpl), my_str)
#[1] "bar foo bar foo foo bar"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `str_replace_all` multiple replacements and moving the first match to a temporary value.

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(my_str, c("foo" = "tmp", "bar" = "foo", "tmp" = "bar"))

[1] "bar foo bar foo foo bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

No real reason to do this unless you're unable to install extra packages, but just for fun here's a base R solution (following the "tmp" replacement method in @manotheshark's answer):

```
Reduce(
  function(prev, x) gsub(x[1], x[2], prev),
  list(c('foo', 'tmp'), c('bar', 'foo'), c('tmp', 'bar')),
  my_str)
# [1] "bar foo bar foo foo bar"
```