# Is it possible to invert all brackets in a file using regex in one parse?

Tags: regex, find-replace

I was asked this in an interview:

---

Simplified Problem Statement:

Consider the following line: `)()()()()(`. (A simple example, this can even be {} and [] with text in the middle)
Write a regex to be used with find replace, that'll invert all brackets.

---

Expected result: `()()()()()`

---

I used a triple parse:

1. change all '(' to '\'
2. change all ')' to '('
3. change all '\' to ')'

---

Can this be done in one go?

Comment: Also, I think you mean for that last one to put `'\' to ')'`

Comment: I don't think so. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483645/replace-one-regex-match-with-another-and-vice-versa

Comment: This question might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367347/replace-x-with-y-and-y-with-x-in-a-single-regular-expression